# Stripe adds shipping cost to non-shippable product

Tags: stripe-payments

I have been testing Stripe API in Test Mode using Stripe's .NET library. So far, I have added two sample products. Both of which costs $5 and one of those is shippable. I have also added flat-rate shipping cost in Business Settings of Stripe Dashboard. The problem is that whenever I create a new order using the following code, Stripe charges shipping cost regardless of the product's Shippable attribute.

```
var service = new StripeOrderService();

options = new StripeOrderCreateOptions
                    {
                        Currency = "usd",
                        CustomerId = user.StripeCustomerId,
                        Email = user.Email,
                        Items = new List<StripeOrderItemOptions>
                        {
                            new StripeOrderItemOptions
                            {
                                Type = "sku",
                                Parent = book.SkuId, // Stripe Product SKU ID,
                                 // SKU means a purchasable unit of Product in this context
                                Quantity = 1,
                                Description = user.Name + " bought " + book.Name
                            },
                        }
                    };
StripeOrder order = service.Create(options);
```

But this does not make any sense why Stripe includes shipping cost in Order of Product which is not shippable. So, how to fix this, what is wrong here?

Comment: That doesn't sound right, you might want to write to Stripe's support with the specific SKU id to investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue, when I integrated third party (shippo) for shipping purpose.

Even though I marked shipable false but it was adding shipping charges.
When contacted to stripe support they accepted that it is really an issue but cannot fix this behavior.

This what they exactly said.

> I went over this with our engineering team, and it took some time to
>   investigate what was happening here, as this was a fairly unusual
>   case. After investigating, the behavior they confirmed finding is as
>   you described where the shippable field on the SKU/product doesn't
>   seem to impact whether or not shipping fees apply, even when the
>   SKU/product is marked unshippable.
>
> Unfortunately it seems this behavior will be difficult to change,
>   which means for the foreseeable future it should be considered that
>   account-level Relay shipping settings could potentially override the
>   shippable boolean at the SKU/product level. Because of this, I would
>   advise against using the global Shipping options and instead choose a
>   callback approach, where we request what the shipping fee should be
>   from your server, and in cases of SKU/products that shouldn't be
>   shippable, that can be set to 0.

Comment: Thanks for posting the email response from people at Stripe. I received the same reply from them a while back, but forgot to post an update here.

Comment: @AsifulNobel 
I tried same thing couple of days back, it seems that stripe has fixed the issue.
Now 'shippable = false' is working fine.